# In Star Wars, did anyone travel outside the Galaxy?

Tags: star-wars

Given the Hyperdrives and other tech in the *Star Wars* universe surely someone has traveled outside the Galaxy? Or does this happen but doesn't impact the stories or characters we know of? (I don't know much outside films and the CW series so be nice).

Comment: It's a good question, but unfortunately one that's already been asked and answered

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'll get the hang of this site yet!